# How to set an input control?

Tags: sql

I have in my table two attributes : SellingPrice & BuyingPrice
I need to make sure that the selling price is always greater than the buying price when i use the insert command .
I'm using Mysql DBMS
My table contains two columns SellingPrice & BuyingPrice
Thank you

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use check constraints

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CHECK (SellingPrice > BuyingPrice);
```

or ( varies depending on RDBMS)

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Table1 CHECK (SellingPrice > BuyingPrice);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_sellingprice_buyingprice
    check (sellingprice > buyingprice);
```

This seems like an odd condition to check, because some things are sometimes sold at a loss.  Your data model does not seem to take that into account.